# Memory usage of Chrome extension is increased slowly with RecordRTC.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory, google-chrome-extension, memory-leaks

In my Chrome extension, the process of the program will do record -> stop -> download infinitely with [RecordRTC.js](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC). Everything can work properly in the beginning, however, the memory usage of my extension is increased slowly. The memory usage can be decreased sometimes, but the trend of memory usage is increased, which may cause the size of recorded file smaller than the file which is recorded in the beginning. I used `setTimeout` and `setInterval` to switch record and stop, thus I guess higher memory usage may impact the performance of my program.

I also used dev tool to check memory usage in `timeline`. The number of listeners is always increased but I cannot find which may be the root cause. Can anyone give any suggestions? Many many many thanks.

Here is my code:

```
          intervalID = setInterval(function(){
     i = i+1;
       recorder.addStream(stream);
     streambk = stream;
       recorder.mediaType = { video: false, audio: true };
       recorder.startRecording();

       timeoutID = setTimeout(function(){ 

      recorder.stopRecording(function(){
          audiobufferr = recorder.audioRecorder.buffer;

          if (i < 100001){          
          var s = document.createElement('a');
          var wrap =_arrayBufferToBase64(audiobufferr); 
          s.href = "data:audio/wav;base64," + wrap; 
          s.download = 'audio-'+i+'.wav'; // Filename
          s.click();     

          chrome.browsingData.removeDownloads({
          "originTypes": {
          "protectedWeb": false, 
          "unprotectedWeb":false,
          "extension":true   
          }},function (){

              });
      }
        else{
            i = 0;
      // clear download history of Browser
         chrome.browsingData.removeDownloads({
          "originTypes": {
          "protectedWeb": false, 
          "unprotectedWeb":false,
          "extension":true   
          }},function (){
                console.log("All (download) data is Deleted...");
              });

       // send message to Native Messaging host and run delete.sh 
     chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage('delete.audio.wav',
    {text: "send"},
    function(response) {console.log("Received " + 
                        chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    });
          }   
        //}             
       }); 

      }, 3500 );    
   }, 3700);
```

Comment: Do note that if you're inspecting something with Dev Tools, that in itself may raise the memory usage (as the logs collected count).

Comment: Thanks for your command. :) I found the situation which you described above during testing the code. Thus, I also closed Dev Tools to monitor the memory usage of extension in Task Manager. The raising of memory usage was still occurred. :(